# Using Mapbox (LeafletJS), how do I edit imported shapes from GeoJSON?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet-draw

**Overview:** I'm currently working on a project where I'm importing GeoJSON into a map using Mapbox. However, I'm wanting to be able to edit those shapes once imported into the map. I've gotten the GeoJSON imported successfully. I can see my shapes as layers in my FeatureGroup. I can see my shapes on the map as they should be rendered.

**The Issue:** The problem that I'm having is editing the layers after I've imported them. When I click on the "edit" button using Leaflet Draw, I'm getting an error saying "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined*" on line 10 of leaflet_draw.js. Also, my shapes are now empty shapes with dashed border and no edit controls. Therefore, I can't even interact with the shapes at all.

**My Code:** Here's the code that I've used to pull my GeoJSON into the map:

```
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
if (oldData) {
    var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(oldData, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlon) {
            if (feature.properties.type === 'circle') {
                return L.circle(latlon, feature.properties.radius);
            } else if (feature.properties.type === 'marker') {
                return L.marker(latlon);
            }
        },
        setStyle: function (feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color};
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
            layer.openPopup();
        }
    }).addTo(featureGroup);
}

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: featureGroup
    },
    draw: {
        polygon: true,
        polyline: true,
        rectangle: true,
        circle: true,
        marker: true
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Also, it may be helpful to know that I'm using Leaflet.draw version 0.2.3 and Leaflet 0.7.2 that come with Mapbox 2.2.1.

Any tips will help.

Comment: Should the second featureLayer variable be added to the featureGroup rather than the map?

Comment: @jmfolds That doesn't seem to be working. I just found a post where someone used `L.geoJson` instead of `L.mapbox.featureLayer` and entered `featureGroup.addLayer(layer);` under `onEachFeature`. That seemed to do the trick to get me to edit the shapes. However, I'm running into issues saving the data. But that may be my answer for now. [Here's a link to the post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892981/load-geojson-in-mapbox-for-editing-with-leaflet-draw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never actually was able to use `L.mapbox.featureLayer` for this. I ended up having to use Leaflet's `L.geoJson`, adding `featureLayer` to map instead of the `featureGroup`, and adding the layer to the `featureGroup` at `onEachFeature`. Here's what my final code looked like:

```
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
if (oldData) {
    var featureLayer = L.geoJson(oldData, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlon) {
            if (feature.properties.type === 'circle') {
                return L.circle(latlon, feature.properties.radius);
            } else if (feature.properties.type === 'marker') {
                return L.marker(latlon);
            }
        },
        style: function (feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color};
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
            layer.openPopup();
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: featureGroup
    },
    draw: {
        polygon: true,
        polyline: true,
        rectangle: true,
        circle: true,
        marker: true
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Here's a Mergely diff showing the difference: http://www.mergely.com/fVq3TQvT/